# How to get access to CFNetworkError cases?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4

Swift prints all network error descriptions in console (from the enum `CFNetworkErrors`?).
But I want to get access to the enum in app so that I can keep track of what error I am getting while the app loads.
I'm following the MVC pattern and tried to get access to errors in my "Model" section. Still I didn't get it right. This is what I did inside `dataTask` in the class where I load the APIs:

```
if self.networkErrors != nil {
    print(self.networkErrors.debugDescription)
}
```

where I declared: `var networkErrors: CFNetworkErrors?`

Do I need to put the cases to check or there is some other way to catch the errors printed in console as in the image?
[Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUMcG.png)

Comment: You can just just `localizedDescription` of an error to print it to users or get `(error as NSError).code` to get the enum code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could access the error code through this simple approach

```
if self.networkErrors != nil {
    print(self.networkErrors.debugDescription)
    print(self.networkErrors._code) // This will print the error code.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ajay-singh-mehra
But will you please elaborate why did you use `._code` and not `.code`?

Comment: .code is not directly accessible from outside, It just a trick what I found by luck

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing!